# How to ensure our business-service is using the same db connection as the servicestack-service

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We do have a few business services, which require an IDBConnection.
It's quite important that these services do use the same dbconnection as the 'normal' Service-Stack service, so we do have atomic transactions.

our current solution for this problem is, to instantiate the business service in the servicestack-service constructor (using the IDbConnection that servicestack provides)

```cs
        private readonly ITaskService _taskService;

        public RegistrationService(IEmailService emailService, ITextProvider textProvider)
        {
            this._taskService = new TaskService(Db);
        }
```

However, I feel like this is not very 'smart' and there might be a way better solution which I'm overlooking right now.

Would a better option be, to inject the DbFactory instead of the plain connection? If so, does DbFactory already solve this problem?

Best,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the same open `Db` connection as that of a ServiceStack Service you should pass it in from your Service, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IMyDep MyDep { get; set; }

    public object Any(MyRequest request)
    {
        MyDep.Method(Db);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can override `GetDbConnection()` in your AppHost to have it return the same db connection for that request, e.g:

```
public override IDbConnection GetDbConnection(IRequest req = null)
{
    if (req != null)
    {
        if (req.Items.TryGetValue("RequestDb", out var oDb) && oDb is IDbConnection db)
            return db;
        db = base.GetDbConnection(req);
        req.Items["RequestDb"] = db;
        return db;
    }
    return base.GetDbConnection(req);
}
```

That in your dependencies can access from `AppHost.GetDbConnection()`, e.g:

```
public class MyDep : IMyDep 
{
    private IDbConnection db;
    public virtual IDbConnection Db => db ?? (db = HostContext.AppHost.GetDbConnection(Request));

    public object Method()
    {
        var row = Db.Select<Table>();
    }
}
```

Comment: putting the connection into the specific methods (instead of the constructor) sounds already like a better solution than we have (especially since we are now able to register it in the di - container). We will go with that. Thank you!